# Apache Storm - LocalCluster stopped logging but java process still running

Tags: java, apache-storm, nohup

We are running a LocalCluster of Apache Storm as a java process i.e via nohup.

We are running a simple Topology with following configuration.

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setMessageTimeoutSecs(120);
config.setNumWorkers(1);
config.setDebug(false);
config.setMaxSpoutPending(1);
```

We are submitting the Topology to LocalCluster.  Our shutdown hook is the default one found across sources.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cluster.killTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME);
                cluster.shutdown();
            }
        });
```

Lately we were facing Java Heap issues which might have been solved by increasing Xms, Xmx and using MarkSweepGC.

However, we are running into new problem. The spout logs are not being written to after sometime. There will be no trace of any storm relate Exception/Error.

The main problem is the java process i.e. via nohup is still showing up in `ps -ef`. What issue would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling debug logging with `config.setDebug(true);`, which might let you tell what is happening.

Also next time your topology hangs, you should be able to tell what it's doing by either using `jstack` or sending the Java process a SIGQUIT (`kill -3`). This will cause the process to dump stack traces for each thread in the JVM, which should let you figure out why it's hanging.

As an aside in case you're doing it, please don't use LocalCluster in production. It's intended for testing.